# How to remove the first element from a list of tuples?

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples like so:

```
x = [("a","b","c"), ("d","e","f"), ("g","h","i"), ("j","k","l")]
```

and I would like to remove the first element from each index like so:

```
x = [("b","c"), ("e","f"), ("h","i"), ("k","l")]
```

I've tried using `pop.x` and `remove.x` like so which doesn't work. I think because the list has tuples which cannot be changed?:

```
for i in result:
    i.pop(0)
```

So I tried to convert the list of tuples to list of lists using a `zip` function but i get an error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'zip' has no attribute 'result'
```

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks for all the useful answers! Many ways to skin a cat that i can use for other problems i encounter =D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A tuple in python is an **unchangeable** object. You can store anything you want in it but once it is declared you cannot change it back.

Here a link to tuples : https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences (section 5.3)

The `pop`function deletes the last element from your list and returns it. Since you have tuples in your list, calling the `pop` function on your list of tuples will only result in returning and deleting the last tuple from your list.

Comment: It's better to link to the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org) than w3schools. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280478/9473764

Comment: duely noted ! will do next time

Answer (score 4):

Tuples are [immutable](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences), so you can't change them. You can however overwrite your list with a list of new tuples:

```py
x = [('a','b','c'), ('d','e','f'), ('g','h','i'), ('j','k','l')]

x = [tpl[1:] for tpl in x]
```

Output:

```
[('b', 'c'), ('e', 'f'), ('h', 'i'), ('k', 'l')]
```

Answer (score 2):

As you've found, tuples are immutable so you must create a new list with tuples that don't contain the items

```
new_list = []

for i in result:
    new_list.append(i[1:])
```

or replace the list items by their index

```
for idx, tup in enumerate(x):
    x[idx] = tup[1:]
```

or as a list comprehension

```
[i[1:] for i in result]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [('a','b','c'), ('d','e','f'), ('g','h','i'), ('j','k','l')]
y = []

for t in x:
   y.append(tuple(list(t)[1:]))
   
print(y)
```

Output

```
[('b', 'c'), ('e', 'f'), ('h', 'i'), ('k', 'l')]
```